# Word for a "waypoint" but along a time dimension?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, phrase-requests, time

I want to be able to say 'After the process has begun, there are these *time waypoints* of 10 seconds, 30 seconds and 70 seconds from the start where I want this action to be performed.'

I suppose I could say **milestones**, or **times**. But I was rather hoping for something better than this. I can't use the term **events** because in the context I'm in that's already a reserved word.

There was [another question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117146/what-word-describes-the-midpoint-between-two-times-when-its-not-exactly-a-mi/117226#117226) I found already that was sort of like this, but I couldn't find the answer I wanted and it is now closed. [Yet another question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27113/word-for-distance-in-time) concerned a word for a time period, or interval, but I want a word for a marker from an absolute point in time (zero) rather than a relative distance.

Comment: *t+n*? "You can start at *t+30* or at *t+70*"

Comment: erm, [timepoint](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63098/timepoint-vs-time-point)

Answer (score 2):

***Instant***, also *moment*

[TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/instant)

> **2**. a particular moment or point in time at the same instant (from Collins Eng.Dict.)

It may be clearer to say 'point on timeline,' though. That expression is already popular.

- … State Change at certain point on timeline
- I needed to make “baby arrives” a bigger focal point on timeline :)
- … determine starting point on timeline
- Jump to Next 'Interesting Point' on timeline
- Previewing audio, without losing point on timeline
- Move to different point on timeline
- How to position playhead to specific point on timeline.

Comment: Keeping the phrasing of the question largely intact, Instant could be used like so: "After the process has begun, there are several instants when I want this action to be performed: start + 10 seconds, 30 seconds and 70 seconds."

Answer (score 1):

I think the word you need is checkpoint.

Its found use in the past few years in the area of Bitcoin and Cryptocurrency. Within the Bitcoin and Cryptocurrency usage, it represents a fixed point in time on the blockchain, at which time certain assumptions can be made that hold true forever.

https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1797/what-are-checkpoints

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can use [**epoch**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/epoch).

From Google,

> *epoch*: a particular period of time in history or a person's life; the beginning of a period in the history of someone or something.

or, as you might be interested ([Source](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/epoch)):

> a :  an event or a time marked by an event that begins a new period or development
>
> b :  a memorable event or date

Given that the context is computer programming, this term is particularly well-suited. I've seen it used in some open-source projects.

Comment: Note the OP's criterion: "Yet another question concerned a word for a time period, or interval, but I want **a word for a marker** from an absolute point in time (zero)"

Comment: @Kris, I'm sure if I understand the word wrong, but according to the usage I usually found in computer program, it is usually used for specifying a point in time, mostly 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970.

Comment: Here is what I found from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/epoch, epoch: 1. a point in time beginning a new or distinctive period.

Comment: *Epoch* is always used in reference to a significant period of time, usually the time period itself, sometimes the beginning of **that period** (when such a beginning is far more significant than the period itself.)

Comment: @Kris, (Note: I don't want to stir things up, just want to clear up my thoughts) What do you think if in the OP's example, I named the time at 10 seconds, 30 seconds and 70 seconds, as Epoch 1, Epoch 2, and Epoch 3, in that order. I believe that it's fine to use these Epochs to refer to both exact point in time and the period from its start time to the next Epoch.

Comment: Then you, as the author, would know what you mean, but how does the reader know if you mean a moment in time or a period in time? If they knew that, where's the problem in the first place :)